# Spring-boot-starter-web 2.4.4 importing spring-web and spring-webmvc versions 4.3.12 being listed as 5.3.5 in pom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, build-dependencies

I am using the `spring-boot-starter-web` version 2.4.4 in my project. When I view its contents, it clearly lists spring-web and spring-webmvc 5.3.5 versions. However, I can see this spring-web and spring-webmvc being pulled into my project with version 4.3.12.RELEASE for some reason. Here is an excerpt from my maven dependency tree, which I has the only occurrence of this spring-web dependency:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.44:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile
```

So I can see based on this graph, spring-boot-starter-web jar 2.4.4 pulls in these dependencies, spring-boot-starter-json, spring-boot-starter-tomcat, and spring-web, and spring-webmvc. I just don't get where this version is coming from , as I would expect another dependency to be pulling it in transitively , but I don't see that in the graph. and if I search my pom.xml for 4.3.12 , I don't have anything listed like that. I have spring-boot-starter-web declared in my POM as such:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.3.5</version>-->
        </dependency>
```

and I am indeed using the spring-boot-starter-parent (version 2.4.4):

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: Worth updating question with complete pom file.

Comment: I have 16 million things in it. No one on here would reading through it. Besides , logically, why would jackson or some other dependencies even have an effect on that? If it  did, it would show up on the Maven dep. tree, which I searched and there was only 1 occurence for spring-web, and its what I posted above.

Comment: As mentioned you only posted a snippet of the dependency tree, you only posted a single part of the pom. Without more information this question is impossible to answer. You are overriding the version somewhere else (like having a `spring.version` in the `<properties>` section for some reason).

Comment: If you want an answer/help don't ask the same question again in an even worse way. Instead include your pom/dependencies and the other relevant info. With only a snippet this is going to be left unanswered.